# Amazon QuickSight - Filter pane

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

This is the first time I have used Amazon QuickSight to create a basic Dashboard. When I tried excluding elements from the visual, the filter pane pops up from the left side. Is it possible to prevent this pop-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When publishing the dashboard, you need to disable the option to **Enable advanced filtering on the left pane**. This should disable the filtering pane from showing up. See [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/creating-a-dashboard.html#:~:text=Clear%20Enable%20advanced%20filtering%20on%20the%20left%20pane](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/creating-a-dashboard.html#:%7E:text=Clear%20Enable%20advanced%20filtering%20on%20the%20left%20pane)